# Span with radio button underneath

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some bootstrap code to have radio buttons to choose a color: http://jsfiddle.net/m4uoo2s9/

The css looks like:

```
.color {
  height: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red { background: red; } /* And I'll have a blue one, and a green one */
```

Right now the radio button has their respective color span to the right. However, I want the radio button to be centered horizontally *under* it's respective color span.

Answer (score 3):

I have create little bit changes in your CSS

```
label{float:left; margin-right:5px}/*Add*/

.color {
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/ /*Remove*/
    display: block;
}

.red { background: red; }
```

********** Modified CSS **********

```
label{float:left; margin-right:5px; text-align:center}/*Add*/


.color {
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/ /*Remove*/
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
}

.red { background: red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zdfqLje/)

Add in your CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{position:absolute; top:30px; display:table}
```

[Modified Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anujsoft/y7j4yx0x/)

Comment: I added a fiddle so the OP can see the results

Comment: @anujsoft, thanks for the answer. Is there anyway to switch it so that the radio button is *underneath* the color span?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided in your JFiddle

1. Change your html so that the span comes before the input:

   ```
   <label class="radio-inline">
     <div class='color red'></div> <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 
   </label>
   ```
2. Also change the span to a div (shown above)
3. Use 'block' instead of 'inline-block' for your `.color` class
4. Set the Labels to float left so that they appear side by side, add a margin or padding for a bit of space.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with absolute positioning? Like so:

```
.radio-inline input{
position:absolute;
top:28px;
margin-left:3px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/beu3mawm/)

Answer (score 0):

Put the radio button input tag below the span tag inside your label element and for the span tag use css property display:block.

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
          <span class='color red' style="display:block;"></span>
          <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    </label>
```